# UITableViewCell custom subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, subview

I have this in my controller:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PostCell";

    PostCell *postCell = (PostCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    Post *post = self.displayPosts[indexPath.row];
    [postCell setPost:post];

    return postCell;
}
```

With `[postCell setPost:post];` I send my custom cell model that its going to use.

```
- (void)setPost:(Post *)newPost
{
    if (_post != newPost) {
        _post = newPost;
    }
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Now this is version that I have but I want to change it. Now I have `[self setNeedsDisplay]` which calls `drawRect` - I want to use `subviews` and dunno how to initiate that.

Where do I add `subviews` and if using `IBOutlets` where do I set subviews values (`imageviews` image, `labels` text etc...) based on that _post ??

Or if easier to point me how to add `buttons` to my cell with drawRect and how to detect `touch` on images and buttons inside `drawRect`? That way I wont need to change current version.

Comment: In your `setPost` function you need to create a view (whatever kind you need) and then add that view as a subview of your cell: `[self.contentView addSubview:newView]`.  Then do it again for any other views you want your cell to contain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)setPost:(Post *)newPost
{
    if (_post != newPost) {
        _post = newPost;
    }

    [self layoutSubviews];
    [self refreshContent];
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    if (self.titleLabel == nil) {
     self.titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
     [self addSubview:self.titleLabel];
    }

    if (self.imageView == nil) {
     self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
     [self addSubview:self.imageView];
    }

    // here I also set frames of label and imageview

}

- (void)refreshContent
{
    [self.titleLabel setText:_post.title];
    [self.imageView setImage:self.post.image];
}
```

This is the way I've done it and it works great without any lags in `UITableView`.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)setPost:(Post *)newPost
{
    if (_post != newPost) {
        _post = newPost;
    }
    //check subviews exist and set value by newPost, if need no view, add subview, if need value, set new value
    //Following code is just sample.
    if(!self.imageView){
       self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
       [self.contentView addSubview:self.imageView];
    }

    if(newImage){
        self.imageView = newImage;
    }

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```